# Error by copy pasting ranged due to merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

SOLVED, SEE CODE BELOW

I'm working on a code for filtering data and pasting the filtered data to the "destination" sheet.
In the "review" sheet there is a long list with data that can be subdivided in certain categories. In cell F9 off the coversheet I can select a category.
After pressing a button the data in the "review" sheet needs to be filtered and the data that is left after filtering should be pasted in the "destination" sheet. the "destination" sheet is a blank new sheet.

The filtering part works, however the copy paste part is giving some errors. Because the "review" sheet has some merged cells in it. I am able to paste the formatting and the columnwidths, but the values give an error due to merged cells. Is there some way to work around this??

In addition to this, when pasting the formatting, this is pasted to the same number of rows as in the "review" sheet before filtering. I want the formatting to be applicable on only the numer of rows left after filtering.

I hope someone can help me out.

See my source code below:

```
Dim wksCVP As Worksheet
Dim wksReview As Worksheet
Dim wksNew As Worksheet

Set wksReview = Worksheets("REVIEW")
Set wksCVP = Worksheets("COVER PAGE")
Set wksNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

wksReview.Cells.Copy wksNew.Cells
wksNew.Cells.UnMerge

Dim LastRow As Long
With wksNew
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Select Case wksCVP.Range("F9").Value
    Case "Instrumentation"
        kolom = "J"
    Case "Equipment"
        kolom = "K"
    Case "Design / Fabrication"
        kolom = "L"
    Case "Inspection & Testing"
        kolom = "M"
    Case "General / Other"
        kolom = "N"
End Select

If wksCVP.Range("F9").Value <> "" Then
    For i = 5 To LastRow
        If wksNew.Range(kolom & i).Value <> "X" Then
            wksNew.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End If

 wksNew.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A5", "Z" & LastRow + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

With Sheets("DESTINATION").Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
End With

wksNew.delete
```

Comment: Can't you just change those merged cells into `center across selection` cells ?

Comment: Can the merged cells be changed to center across selection cells by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `Formats` and the `ColumnWidths` being in a merged cell, which is only partially copied, the easiest way is to add a new worksheet, to copy the initial values there and to unmerge it. Then do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim wksTheNew           As Worksheet
    Dim wksReview           As Worksheet
    Dim wksDestination      As Worksheet

    Set wksReview = Worksheets("Review")
    Set wksDestination = Worksheets("Destination")

    Set wksTheNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    wksReview.Cells.Copy wksTheNew.Cells
    wksTheNew.Cells.UnMerge

    'now copy the formats and the values from wksTheNew
    'it will not give an error, because it is unmerged

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wksTheNew.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Once you are ready with your actions, you may simply delete the new worksheet.

Comment: when I do this it doesn't take in account that the hidden rows shouldn't be copied to the "destination" sheet

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sequence:

```
With Sheets("DESTINATION").Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
End With
```

Pasting values first shouldn't trigger an error.

Comment: It works for the copy pasting, but this also doesnt take in account that the hidden rows shouldnt be pasted to the "destination" sheet. Is there a way to only let the copy pasting affect the visible rows?

Comment: Humm... I used Autofilter. With autofilter it works, can you use it?

Comment: unfortunately not, but I think I solved it. If I use the solution below, unmerge the cells in a new worksheet. Then hide the rows. Then copy paste, with adding {.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)} before {.copy}

Comment: Ok, you solved with `.SpecialCells`, so you don't need a new worksheet, as @vityata answered. You changed your question, but using "Paste all" you wouldn't get problem you originally want to solve.